# Traverse an array and get lowest 2 entries for a given name

Tags: arrays, node.js, lodash

I have an array with a key "name", and "points". There can be multiple entries for a particular name. What would be the ideal way to form a new array with name, points and a new key type based on points.
Example:
input:

```
[{"name":"A", "points": 9},
{"name":"A", "points": 5},
{"name":"A", "points": 4},
{"name":"A", "points": 1},
{"name":"A", "points": 3},
{"name":"A", "points": 6},
{"name":"B", "points": 5},
{"name":"B", "points": 1},
{"name":"B", "points": 2},
{"name":"B", "points": 3}]

Lowest points - typeA
Second lowest points - typeB
```

Output:

```
[{"name":"A", "points": 1, "type":"typeA"},
{"name":"A", "points": 3, "type":"typeB"},
{"name":"B", "points": 1, "type":"typeA"},
{"name":"B", "points": 2, "type":"typeB"}]
```

Comment: If your desired output has different number of rows than the input, lodash does not help you much. The standard for-cycle would be your friend here.

Comment: @libik I have edited the question for using normal traversal which should be optimal, as the list might be about 1000-2000 long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this would be a good solution:

```
const input = [{"name":"A", "points": 9},
                {"name":"A", "points": 5},
                {"name":"A", "points": 4},
                {"name":"A", "points": 1},
                {"name":"A", "points": 3},
                {"name":"A", "points": 6},
                {"name":"B", "points": 5},
                {"name":"B", "points": 1},
                {"name":"B", "points": 2},
                {"name":"B", "points": 3}];

//this function will be passed to Array's "reduce" function, and will return the item with the lowest points
const reduceLowest = (lowest, current) => current.points < lowest.points ? current : lowest;

//this function receives an item and returns a new item with an additional "type" property
const addType = (item, typeToAdd) => { return { name : item.name, points : item.points, type : typeToAdd } };

//this function receives an array and returns another array with its two lowests items (typeA and typeB)
const returnTypeATypeB = (arr) => {

    var lowestTypeA = arr       
        .reduce(reduceLowest) //gets the lowest item
        ;

    var lowestTypeB = arr
        .filter((item) => item != lowestTypeA) //removes the item that already is the lowest from the array     
        .reduce(reduceLowest) //gets the lowest item
        ;

    //return an array containing the typeA and typeB items
    return [ addType(lowestTypeA, "typeA"), addType(lowestTypeB, "typeB")];

};          

const output = 
    returnTypeATypeB(
        input.filter((item) => item.name === "A")
    ) //gets typeA and typeB from the items which contains the name "A"
    .concat( //concat the previous list with..
        returnTypeATypeB(
            input.filter((item) => item.name === "B") 
        ) //typeA and typeB from the items which contains the name "B"
    );

console.log(output);
//prints..
// [ { name: 'A', points: 1, type: 'typeA' },
//  { name: 'A', points: 3, type: 'typeB' },
//  { name: 'B', points: 1, type: 'typeA' },
//  { name: 'B', points: 2, type: 'typeB' } ]
```

Comment: @demarchid Thanks for the idea. I actually did by sorting based on name and then on points. Then sliced the first 2 of each name and added type accordingly. Had to generalize it as the list is large, not just A n B.

Comment: Is there an npm module for object array natural sort based 2 keys